# How to change the process group id of a process

Tags: c, linux, process

I am trying to write a code in which a signal has to be broadcasted to a number of processes (without using a simple loop to send the signal to every process individually).

My plan was to set the process group id of all the processes to the same gid as that of the sender process and then use `kill(0,SIGUSR1)` to send the signal to all processes in the group. But whenever I am trying to perform the system call `setpgid(0,pgid)`, it is giving the error: `Could not change gid: Operation not permitted`.

My codes for these two processes are:

```
#include "cn.h"
// sender process

void sig_handler(int alrm)
{
    printf("Signal Received\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGUSR1,sig_handler);
    printf("%d\n",(int)getpgid(0)); //print the gid and wait before proceeding
    getchar();
    if(setpgid(0,100)<0)
    {
        perror("Could not change gid");
    }
    kill(0,SIGUSR1);
    return 0;
}
```

And for the receiving process:

```
#include "cn.h"

void sig_handler(int alrm)
{
    printf("Signal Received\n");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGUSR1,sig_handler);
    int d;
    scanf("%d",&d); //take input of the gid and then change it
    if(setpgid(0,d)<0)
    {
        perror("Could not change gid");
    }
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing? What changes do I need to make in order to allow the process to change its own process group id?

Comment: Use `pause();` to do nothing until a signal arrives.  It’s better than an empty infinite loop.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, that's true, but then the process will end after receiving the signal, right?

Comment: It will end if you’ve not set signal handling, just as the loop will.  The main difference is that the CPU is not busy spinning its wheels while doing nothing, so other programs can use it. There are also obscure arguments about optimizations that might be relevant.

Comment: The failure could be because you're providing a target pgid that is not in the same session.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Neither of these programs launches the other, but normally, the processes need to have some common ancestor that sets the process group.  You should look at the errors for [`setpgid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgid.html); maybe 
[`setpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setpgrp.html) would help.  Note that process group leaders cannot alter their own PGID.  Also, a child inherits its parent's PGID.

Comment: Process groups are designed to enable a shell to move jobs between foreground and background, and to route tty-initiated signals (SIGINT for Ctrl-C, etc.) to the correct set of processes. The shell is a session leader and its descendants belong to its session, and it has no business manipulating processes outside that session. If your proposed use of process groups is wildly different from that, you may be in trouble.